# Is it a good practice to unset cookie expire parameter?

Tags: php

I see the usage of the following code snippet:

```
    $cookieexpiry=(time()+21600);
    setcookie("rwphp","$cookieid",$cookieexpiry,"/",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],0);
    unset($cookieexpiry);
```

Q1> My question is whether or not this is a good practice to unset $cookieexpiry.

Q2> In general cases, when should I unset variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing the unset is going to do in this case is free up the variable $cookieexpiry. It is not going to have any affect on your cookie itself.

I think you are a little confused about that because of the name of your variable, but all $cookieexpiry is is the number representing the time and nothing more.

I have seen unset used very rarely, you would unset if you needed that variable name again for something, but I believe most people would use a different variable name if they needed it again.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to unset it at all. The garbage collector will take care of it. Only moment I would think you need to unset is if you need the variable to be inexistent later on in your code.

Maybe I am overlooking something.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) for the doc about unset()

One reason to unset would be to free up some memory after you are done with some HUGE object.
Thanks ovais.tariq

Comment: garbage collection does happen,. but suppose you are running some kind of a very large script that creates complex objects,. then it would be a good idea to unset the variables holding those complex objects if they are not required any further,. otherwise in some case you might get memory exhausted errors in php

Comment: @ovais good comment although I would have to say your application would have to be pretty large to exhaust memory.

Comment: @chris., yeah you are right., but i thought its something that the questioner should know., it might happen in some kind of data migration script,.

Answer (score 1):

unsetting the cookieexpiry variable like you have shown is not going to make much difference here because it doesnt hold substantial data,.

unset is useful when you have previously stored some large data in a variable, like for example a complex object and that variable is not being used further